# A question regarding 'Uniformization' theorem : connection between a topological space and a uniform spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, uniform-spaces

This title might be slightly misleading since I saw that the name 'uniformization' theorem is already used in a different context, but my question regards whether a topological space arises from a uniformity.

I know that there is a  [metrization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata%E2%80%93Smirnov_metrization_theorem)  characterizing fully a metrizable topological space. I was wondering whether there is a similar result regarding if a topological space is 'uniformisable', even partially. I have very little acquaintace with uniform spaces, so I would appreciate even simple somewhat 'obvious' answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, such a theorem exists: the topology of a topological space $X$ is induced by a uniform structure if and only $X$ is [completely regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space); in other words, if it is a $T_{3\frac12}$ space.

Comment: That is, if you want a separated uniformity. Otherwise leave out the $T_1$ part.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: what is a separated uniformity?